# Hightcharts dashboard error with zooming in and out

Tags: highcharts

I came across a weird error. I'm using a highcharts dashboards demo and tried to implement it in my cshtml project. Whenever I try to zoom into the page it just throws an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stacks') multiple times and chart scaling does not work

Note: whenever I tried to copy it into a jsfiddle it magically works and throws no error so I have actually no clue what this is all about, might be a problem with me importing libraries but I hope somebody might help me.

```
    <body>
    
    <div id="container"></div>

    <pre id="csv">Food,Vitamin A
        Beef Liver,6421
        Lamb Liver, 2122
        Cod Liver Oil, 1350
        Mackerel, 388
        Tuna, 214</pre>
    
    <script>
        const csvData = document.getElementById('csv').innerText;

        Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.download = function (x, y, w, h) {
            const path = [

                'M', x + w * 0.5, y,
                'L', x + w * 0.5, y + h * 0.7,

                'M', x + w * 0.3, y + h * 0.5,
                'L', x + w * 0.5, y + h * 0.7,
                'L', x + w * 0.7, y + h * 0.5,

                'M', x, y + h * 0.9,
                'L', x, y + h,
                'L', x + w, y + h,
                'L', x + w, y + h * 0.9
            ];
            return path;
        };

        let board = Dashboards.board('container', {
            dataPool: {
                connectors: [{
                    id: 'Vitamin',
                    type: 'CSV',
                    options: {
                        csv: csvData,
                        firstRowAsNames: true
                    }
                }]
            },
            editMode: {
                enabled: true,
                contextMenu: {
                    enabled: true,
                    items: ['editMode']
                }
            },
            gui: {
                layouts: [
                    {
                        id: 'layout-1',
                        rowClassName: 'custom-row',
                        cellClassName: 'custom-cell',
                        rows: [
                            {
                                cells: [
                                    {
                                        id: 'dashboard-col-0',
                                        width: '50%'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        id: 'dashboard-col-1'
                                    },
                                    {
                                        id: 'dashboard-col-12'
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            components: [{
                sync: {
                    visibility: true,
                    highlight: true,
                    extremes: true
                },
                connector: {
                    id: 'Vitamin'
                },
                cell: 'dashboard-col-0',
                type: 'Highcharts',
                columnAssignment: {
                    Food: 'x',
                    'Vitamin A': 'value'
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'pie'
                    },
                    exporting: {
                        buttons: {
                            customButton: {
                                symbol: 'download',
                                onclick: function () {
                                    this.downloadXLS();
                                },
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                }
            },
            {
                cell: 'dashboard-col-1',
                sync: {
                    visibility: true,
                    highlight: true,
                    extremes: true
                },
                connector: {
                    id: 'Vitamin'
                },
                type: 'Highcharts',
                columnAssignment: {
                    Food: 'x',
                    'Vitamin A': 'y'
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'category'
                    },
                    chart: {
                        animation: false,
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    exporting: {
                        buttons: {
                            customButton: {
                                symbol: 'download',
                                onclick: function () {
                                    this.downloadXLS();
                                },
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                }
            },
            {
                cell: 'dashboard-col-12',
                connector: {
                    id: 'Vitamin'
                },
                type: 'DataGrid',
                editable: true,
                sync: {
                    highlight: true
                }
            }]
        });


        </script>
```

this site won't let me upload code with all of the script imports

Comment: Hello, could you please provide clarification regarding the zooming you mentioned? Is it related to using shortcuts like Ctrl + /, built-in zoom functionality, or zooming with the touchpad, etc.? Additionally, could you confirm if the issue occurs when working on a regular non-cshtml project? Also, does the problem persist in regular HC (without dashboards)? Thank you!